# Reputation points earned solely by asking questions

Tags: discussion, reputation

During the recent moderator election I found myself wondering if there are any high-rep users (> 10K) who have amassed that many reputation points solely by asking questions and not by answering any.

I'm not interested in identifying particular users, but do we have a way of finding the highest reps built entirely from asking?

**Edit**
I have spent some time trying to convert the two Data Explorer queries that Martin posted into one that would do what I want. My SQL skills aren't great, however, and I have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: Using [data explorer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) you can find users with highest total score [from answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/889444/top-users-based-on-score-from-answers) and [from questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/889445/top-users-based-on-score-from-questions). Total score is different from reputation earned (for example, it does not take into account reputation cap), but it is a rough approximation.

Comment: @PeterPhipps Would you clarify a bit what exactly do you want to achieve "by combining two queries into one"? It's a bit unclear to me what *exactly* you're looking for. If you wish, we can discuss this further [in the SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223/2018/8/27) so that we do not leave too many comments here.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I was trying to combine the question and answer queries into one that selected users with a total answer score of zero and then ordered by total question score.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I rewrote query by Martin Sleziak into this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/891053/top-users-with-no-answer-scores?num=100

Hope it helps.

If still joining on users, you can explicitly view reputation:

https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/891096/top-reputation-users-with-no-answer-score?num=100

It turns out that the top user without answer scores is [Laila Podlesny](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/76878/laila-podlesny), and her reputation is still under 10k.

Comment: As [pointed out by Peter Taylor](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7186968#7186968), it should be possible get rid of the join of two tables without influencing the results.

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: Thanks Nik Pronko and @MartinSleziak, that's just what I wanted.

Comment: Perhaps its worth noting that [Laila Podlesny](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/76878/laila-podlesny) earned her $3722$ reputation points by asking only $33$ questions, an impressive average of more than $100$ points (corresponding to more than $20$ upvotes) per question. And this is just because of daily point restrictions -- she actually got a total of $1300$ upvotes, a remarkable average of almost $40$ per question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer --- It might be interesting to modify this SEDE: [Who is the user with highest combined reputation from all Stack Exchange sites?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483627/who-is-the-user-with-highest-combined-reputation-from-all-stack-exchange-sites) so that it considers 'question only' users instead of total score on all sites.

Comment: @joriki And gave away over 3000 reputation in bounties.

Comment: Note: owing to the great reputation give-away (when upvotes on questions became worth +10 rep points),  user [Laila Podlesny](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/76878/laila-podlesny) has passed the 10K threshhold.